# How to call Explicit Instantiation Declarations function from main()in template? can you explain with the code given below

Tags: c++

```
template<class T> 
class Array 
{
 public:void mf(); #1
};
template class Array<char>;      // explicit instantiation #2
template void Array<int>::mf();  // explicit instantiation #3

void main()
{
  Array<double> a; // implicit instantiation

// my question is how to call mf() in #2 (explict declaration)from main()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, so apologies if I've got the wrong end of the stick.

You call the function on the explicit instantiation just as you would on an implicit instantiation, i.e.

```
Array<char> c;
c.mf();
```

For this to work, there must be either a definition of `Array<T>::mf()` available when `Array<char>` is explicitly instantiated, or a specialisation of `Array<char>::mf()` defined. So the above code will work if you either have:

```
template <typename T> void Array<T>::mf() {cout << "Hello\n";}
template class Array<char>;
```

or

```
template <> void Array<char>::mf() {cout << "Hello\n";}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.mf();
```

(If you really didn't know that, Stackoverflow isn't what you need. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) for help.)